getting csrk token issue in cakephp while cashfree integation
I am working on cakephp project. And i have almost completed the payment integration of cashfree.
While returning from cashfree payment gateway, I am getting the csrf token issue in the cakephp application.
I have used the $_POST in the cakephp code. Please help me in fixing it.
followed the cashfree documentation

Cashfree returns to merchant website using $_GET, so your return url should be able to accept GET

@mohit For Cashfree's latest payment integration, ensure that your callback method is a GET call, not a POST call. Additionally, remember to verify the order details in the callback method. Below is a sample CakePHP controller and view with sample code:
This is Controller
<?php
// src/Controller/ArticlesController.php
namespace App\Controller;
use Cashfree\Model\CreateOrderRequest;
use Cashfree\Model\CustomerDetails;
use Cashfree\Model\OrderMeta;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Cashfree\Cashfree;
class PaymentsController extends AppController
{
public function index()
{
    Cashfree::$XClientId = "XXXXXXXXX_Client_ID";
    Cashfree::$XClientSecret = "XXXXXXX_Client_Secret_Key";
    Cashfree::$XEnvironment = Cashfree::$SANDBOX;
    $cashfree = new Cashfree();

    $x_api_version = "2022-09-01";
    $orderAmount = "10.00"; //Amount should be pass here
    $customerName = "Test Customer";
    $customerEmail = "testcustomer@gmail.com";
    $customerId = "customerId";
    $customerPhone = "9999999999";
    $returnUrl = 'http://localhost/payments/callback?order_id={order_id}'; // Ensure the return URL is correct. I have created a callback get method below this method
    $create_orders_request = new CreateOrderRequest();
    $create_orders_request->setOrderAmount($orderAmount);
    $create_orders_request->setOrderCurrency("INR");
    $customer_details = new CustomerDetails();
    $customer_details->setCustomerName($customerName);
    $customer_details->setCustomerId($customerId);
    $customer_details->setCustomerEmail($customerEmail);
    $customer_details->setCustomerPhone($customerPhone);
    $create_orders_request->setCustomerDetails($customer_details);
    $order_meta = new OrderMeta();
    $order_meta->setReturnUrl($returnUrl);
    $create_orders_request->setOrderMeta($order_meta);

    try {
        $result = $cashfree->PGCreateOrder($x_api_version, $create_orders_request);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Exception when calling PGCreateOrder: ', $e->getMessage(), PHP_EOL;
    }
    
    $payment_session_id = $result[0]['payment_session_id'];
    $data = [
        'payment_session_id' => $payment_session_id,
        'environment' => 'sandbox',
    ];
    
    $this->set($data);
    
}

public function callback()
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    die();
}
}

This the view template placed in /Users/yourusername/your_workplace_dir/cakephp/templates/Payments/index.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cashfree Checkout Integration</title>
    <script src="https://sdk.cashfree.com/js/v3/cashfree.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <p>Click below to open the checkout page in current tab</p>
        <button id="renderBtn">Pay Now</button>
    </div>
    <script>
        const cashfree = Cashfree({
            mode: "<?= h($environment) ?>",
        });
        document.getElementById("renderBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
            let checkoutOptions = {
                paymentSessionId: "<?= h($payment_session_id) ?>",
                redirectTarget: "_self",
            };
            cashfree.checkout(checkoutOptions);
        });
    </script>
</body>

Feel free to adjust the code snippets and explanations based on your specific integration needs and requirements. Let me know if you have any further questions or need additional assistance!

It is really a great help. Thank you for your detailed description.  One small query. Can you suggest the plugin name. So that i will use by composer

I have done all the changes. while return, i am getting only order id.                       Array
(
[order_id] => 67676
)

@MohithaatozservicesMohithaato yes you will get only order_id, After that you have to call cashfree get payments detail to verify the order at your end. This also mentioned in cashfree-php-sdk. For reference please go through this docs
https://github.com/cashfree/cashfree-pg-sdk-php/blob/master/docs/Payments.md
